# Asynctask causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-play

I have an app on Google play. I got a few error reports from the developer page and It's quite hard to figure out the problem.

This is what I have:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.seb.example.free.MainActivity$ApplyFilter.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:828)
at com.seb.example.free.MainActivity$ApplyFilter.onPostExecute(v.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see I have an asynctask innerclass and the error seems to be in on postexecute.
I have checked my project in eclipse and, as the stacktrace says, the error is on line 828:

```
(iV.getVisibility() == ImageView.INVISIBLE)
```

My imageView, iV, is declared as private in MainActivity and I initiate it in oncreate. 
I can't reproduce the problem on the three of my phones as i have tested on, so it's quite hard to understand what's causing it.

Anyone who has any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Initialize it in onResume()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that imageview object is becomes null in some where in your code..check whether it initialized or not..and if initialized check where it is used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

It might have been derefferenced in some other place, initialize in onresume and see whether this persists or not.

Answer (score 0):

please check have you initialized `iv`
try:

```
if(iv != null)
(iV.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
else
Log.e("CHECK","iv Null");
```

if you have not initialized iv then do that first.